# Want to put span on top of the div and to change the font in html

Tags: html, css

I wanted to put text left to the image and on top of the div. I have changed the text type from "p" to "span" and changed the image display type from block to inline-block and it moved from the bottom of the image to left. But now I want to put it on top of this .section div I have tried to make some margin from the bottom but it didn't work.

[image: How is it looking :(]

```css
.section {
  height: 80px;
  background: #dedede;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.modtitle {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

.modimg {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Mods:</h1>
  <div class="section">
    <img class="modimg" src="./img/jei.png" width="80" height="80">
    <span class="modtitle">JEI</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a simple picture that shows your desired result and add it to your question? I'm not sure what you actually want to achieve here :)

Comment: `.modimg` has `margin: left;` this is invalid css, take a look here for all the options available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: So you wish the text `JEI` to be out of the grey container shown in the image using margin?, where should it endup as it seems to be overlapping the text `Mods:` when doing so